# Resources for metrics about brands

Tags: resource-recommendations, branding, marketing, trademark

I love the site [Emblemetric](http://www.emblemetric.com/) but I've read everything on there since it's not updated so often. Where can I find other resources dedicated to metrics and analyzing logo trends?

Comment: Possibly useful: http://www.underconsideration.com/brandnew/

Comment: Brand New is definitely one of my go-to sites but I'm specifically looking for metrics.

Comment: What types of metrics? Are you interested only in evolution and trends, or are considerations like sentiment and ROI important to you as well?

Comment: I'm not sure if you had anything in mind but any serious quantitative research regarding brand design could be of interest.

Answer (score 1):

Emilie, I think Logo Lounge is a good place to go to. They do have posts that bring together the trends for the whole year.Here is 2013 logo trends [2013 Trends](http://www.logolounge.com/article/2013logotrends) The website is constantly updated with website logo reviews and they also research thoroughly about about existing logo changes. [Netflix logo change 2014](http://www.logolounge.com/article.asp?aid=lkSg#.U3OZGyght) Hope this is what you are looking for :)

[Logo Lounch](http://www.logolounge.com/index.asp)

Comment: Do you mind explaining a little more about Logo Lounch instead of providing a link only answer?  Also, do you have anything more to add because if the site were to ever go down your answer would probably receive downvotes in the future.  If you don't have anything else to add I will probably convert this to a comment, just an FYI.

Comment: Gramps, sorry but I was not able to add a comment earlier (not enough reputation). I edited the answer added a bit more information. If you think it is needed to be converted to a comment please do so. Thanks for the tips.

Answer (score -1):

Emilie.

I am a huge fan of this style and in my opinion it's not a style. It's the way logos should be.

I am from Bulgaria which used to be a socialist country some 20-30 years ago. Back then the ruling party had a few designers that designed everything and they did a great job. I am actually amazed by their work which stands the test of time.
My personal hero is Stefan Kanchev. Some research was done in attempt to make a collection of his work but a lot of it was lost. Here it is:

http://stefankanchev.com/en/default.html

There is another website trying to collect the work of socialist designers in Bulgaria and the collection is here:

http://socmus.com/en

Both websites are worth seeing. :)

Comment: Nice sites but this doesn't attempt to answer my question at all, sorry.